# Reliably check for whether a class template has been instantiated, with C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, template-instantiation

It used to be possible, using some C++ compilers, to check whether a templated type has already been instantiated, so that the following program syntax compiles without error:

```
template <typename T> struct MyStruct { };

// some magic goes here

int main () {
    static_assert(!is_instantiated<MyStruct<int>>(), "failure");
    MyStruct<int> a;
    static_assert(is_instantiated<MyStruct<int>>(), "failure");
}
```

The "magic" was in the solution to this question:

[Compile time template instantiation check](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28179835/1593077)

However - that [no longer works](https://godbolt.org/z/XYkM9d) (Godbolt.org) with recent GCC and Clang versions. Also, the user who wrote the accepted answer for that question has left SO and will not be updating it...

So, my question: **Is it possible to reliably check whether a class/struct template has been instantiated for a certain type?**

Notes:

- Looking for a solution using C++11 - not anything later.
- "It's impossible" is a valid answer, but - only if you can justify it.
- Related: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33453352/1593077).
- If it makes it easier, you *may* assume that the class is *possible* to instantiate; but it's better if you don't.

Comment: @walnut: Ok, so, I'll just drop the function templates extra-question, for better focus here and not to confuse people.